# How to validate a drop down menu in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi I'm a relative beginner. I need each object in my form to be validated and basically I don't know how to validate a drop-down menu. Here is my HTML, thanks guys.

```
<div id="valAlert"></div>
        <form name="review" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <div id="valAlert"></div>
                <fieldset>
                    Title: <input type="text" name="Title"><br/>
                    Email Address: <input type="text" name="Email"><br/>
                    Rating: <select name="Rating">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                        <option value="1">Excellent</option>
                        <option value="2">Good</option>
                        <option value="3">Bad</option>
                        <option value="4">Awful</option>
                        </select><br/>
                    <textarea name ="Comments" rows="8" colspan="40">Comments: </textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <input class="button" type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
                    </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: What serverside language are you using? I would advice to implement serverside validation as well.

Comment: It won't leave me add my JavaScript! I'l be using PHP it's just for a college project. I have JavaScript validation for everything except the select option.

Comment: Well if it is an IT project, you're better of implementing it as well. What is the error on the script? Are you using the jQuery lib?

Comment: I actually worked it out there after hours of searching online turned out I forgot a bracket! Thanks, although I feel this site is very unfair as my reputation has been severely knocked because my JavaScript wouldn't format properly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     `else if (r=="0"){
```

document.getElementById("valAlert").innerHTML="We require a rating";
  return false;
  } `